# Live no Facebook

Tags: php, facebook

Estou usando `ffmpeg` para tentar transmitir uma live no Facebook, usando a função `concat` para transmitir múltiplos arquivos de vídeo, porém ao fim do primeiro arquivo, o Facebook trava e não continua reproduzindo o restante dos arquivos.

Essa é minha lista.txt

```
file 'media/inicio.mp4'
file '../../video/arquivo01.mp4'
file '../../video/arquivo02.mp4'
file '../../video/arquivo03.mp4'
file 'media/encerramento.mp4'
```

E estou usando a página abaixo para fazer a transmissão:

```
$chave = "chave-do-facebook";

ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -re -i lista.txt -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -maxrate 3000k -bufsize 6000k -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 50 -c:a aac -b:a 160k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -f flv "'.$chave.'" 2> log.txt
```

Ao iniciar uma transmissão na prévia, já é possível ver o vídeo de inicio, porém, quando o mesmo termina, a live trava e a reprodução não continua.

Ao analisar os logs do `ffmpeg`, ao fim primeiro vídeo a seguinte mensagem aparece:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000000000123ef40] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
[h264 @ 00000000008f08e0] top block unavailable for requested intra mode
[h264 @ 00000000008f08e0] error while decoding MB 34 0
[h264 @ 00000000008f08e0] concealing 3600 DC, 3600 AC, 3600 MV errors in I frame
```

E então esta fica se repetindo até que eu feche a live:

```
[h264 @ 00000000008f1740] QP 4294967211 out of range
[h264 @ 00000000008f1740] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 00000000008f1740] no frame!
```

Cheguei a pensar que o erro estava na codificação dos arquivos que fiz usando Sony Vegas, que no caso são o `inicio.mp4` e `encerramento.mp4`, porém, codifiquei os mesmos em três programas diferentes e até mesmo upei-os para o Youtube e baixei novamente, e mesmo assim continua dando o mesmo erro.

Comment: Acho que a pergunta é interessante pelo conhecimento envolvido, mas é fora do escopo deste site por não ser sobre programação (e sim sobre o uso de uma ferramenta, o ffmpeg). De todas as formas, você sabe que não precisa reinventar a roda né? Já ouviu falar do [OBS](https://obsproject.com/)? Além de [um bom guia no site da ferramenta](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/how-to-stream-to-facebook-live.391/), há vários tutoriais por aí de como usá-lo para fazer live no FB. Por exemplo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_3zrWLzR6jA.

Comment: Não, por reinventar a roda eu dizia tentar reconstruir o que o OBS faz, afinal, **ele usa o ffmpeg** (de forma que o custo de processamento vai ser essencialmente o mesmo). Eu não entendi o que vc quis dizer com "filmando e enviando ao mesmo tempo". O que você vai usar como entrada para o seu streaming (seja um input de câmera, seja de um aruquivo de vídeo) é definido no OBS via as "fontes" ("sources"). O OBS tem justamente uma fonte chamada "media source" que lê arquivos de vídeo para fazer o streaming.

Comment: Eu estava escrevendo o meu "reply" quando você aparentemente apagou o seu comentário. De todas as formas, era só uma dica. Eu posso estar enganado, mas pra mim parece que vc só vai ter dificuldades adicionais em tentar fazer diretamente no ffmpeg.

Comment: Eu removi o comentário pois soou um pouco "mal educado" minha resposta, eu preferiria fazer pelo ffmpeg justamente pelo conhecimento envolvido em tal, tenho conhecimento em OBS  e já até o usei algumas vezes para a mesma função, obrigado pela dica, se alguém vier a responder sobre como fazer com ffmpeg vai ser de ajuda também.

Comment: Não foi mal educado não. :) Bom, se você prefere para aprendizado, eu acho justíssimo. Infelizmente ainda acho que não tá muito no escopo deste site (estaria mais no escopo se vc quisesse fazer, ainda que para aprendizado, utilizando a API do ffmpeg em alguma linguagem de programação). Mas, é isso. Foi só um comentário pra tentar ajudar. Boa sorte! :)

Comment: Estou usando PHP para tentar transmitir essa live, mas como a dúvida não abrange nada sobre PHP em si, acho que não entra no escopo mesmo.

Comment: Somente com o ffmpeg eu não conheco, mas usando o [PhatomJS](http://phantomjs.org/), acredito que você consiga fazer o que esta querendo, mas sendo sincero acho o OBS um jeito muito mais facil de fazer transmissões. phantomjs phantom.js | ffmpeg -y \ -c:v mjpeg \ -f image2pipe \ -framerate 5 \ -i - \ -r 30 \ -c:v libx264 \ -x264-params keyint=60 \ -b:v 1000k \ -minrate 1000k \ -maxrate 1000k \ -bufsize 500k \ -f flv 'rtmp://rtmp-api.facebook.com:80/rtmp/chaveparatransmissao' Boa sorte!